# Update/insert missing date ranges from new data?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Below is TableA present in oracle database.

```
item    price   start_date  end_date
xyz     256     1-Jan-15    17-Jan-15
xyz     125     16-Mar-15   31-Mar-15
```

Below is the new data client provided.

```
item    price   start_date  end_date
xyz     236     5-Jan-15    10-Jan-15
xyz     253     15-Jan-15   20-Jan-15
xyz     253     25-Jan-15   2-Mar-15
```

Now i need to compare above new data to TableA data and fill missing date ranges. If new data have date gap then it must be taken from TableA(if present).
The final updated TableA must be like below:

```
item    price   start_date  end_date
xyz     256     1-Jan-15    4-Jan-15
xyz     236     5-Jan-15    10-Jan-15
xyz     256     11-Jan-15   14-Jan-15
xyz     253     15-Jan-15   20-Jan-15
xyz     253     25-Jan-15   2-Mar-15
xyz     125     3-Mar-15    31-Mar-15
```

This need to be done in oracle using sql/plsql.
Please help.

Seems it can be achieved using lead/lag functions but not sure how to include price field in the query. some thing like below

```
select t.ITEM, t.start_dAtE,
       lead(t.start_dAtE) over (partition by t.ITEM order by t.start_dAtE)-1 as end_dte,
       t.PRICE
from ((select ITEM, start_dAtE,end_date,PRICE
       from xxa
      ) union all
      (select ITEM, start_dAtE,end_date, PRICE
       from xxb
      )
     ) t
group by t.ITEM, t.start_dAtE,t.PRICE;
```

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You could slect data from tables, and then only select the ones where something from TableA matches the same value in TableB.

For example: 
To select the ones that occur in both tables:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    TableA TA, TableB TB
WHERE   TA.item = TB.item 
AND     TA.price = TB.price 
AND     TA.start_date = TA.start_date 
AND     TA.end_date = TA.end_date;
```